# Question about rule on a child in firebase realtime database and readability from a client

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Given the rules on a "chat" node in the realtime databse:

```
"chats": {
  "$chatUID": {
    "$messageUID": {
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['message', 'date', 'from', 'to'])",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null", // unauthorized users should not be able to even try to send data here
      ".read": "data.child('from').val() === auth.uid || data.child('to').val() === auth.uid",
      "from": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
      },
      "to": {
        ".validate": "root.child('friends/' + newData.val() + '/' + auth.uid).exists()"
      },
      "message": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length < 256"
      },
      "date": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() == now" // ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
      },
      "$other": {
        ".validate": false
      }
    }
  }
} // chats
```

can a client retrieve the data on $chatUID ordering the childs by date? Currently $chatUID has no read rules and I'm afraid even tho I will accomplish the requirements on $messageUID for read, I will not be able to obtain any data from $chatUID unless I know a specific $messageUID. Is that correct or I can still use client side queries on $chatUID given the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking if this query is allowed by your rules:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("chats").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
ref.orderByChild("date").once("value", ...
```

What the Firebase Database server does in this case, is check whether the user has permission to read `/chats/$uid`. Since nobody has read permission there, the listener is rejected.

Many developers that are new to Firebase expect the security rules to actively filter the data, but that is not how they work. All they do is check if the entire operation is allowed, and they do that as soon as you attach the listener. In other words: [security rules cannot be used to filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).

However since about a year ago you can [use security rules to validate certain types of filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules). With that you could for example only allow reads that filter the data by `from`.

So for example these rules on `/chats/$uid`:

```
".read": "auth.uid != null &&
        query.orderByChild == 'from' &&
        query.equalTo == auth.uid"
```

would allow this query:

```
ref.orderByChild("from").equalTo(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).once("value", ...
```

While it would reject

```
ref.once("value", ...
```

This means you can allow certain queries, while rejecting other reads. However I don't think it's possible to require multiple clauses, as needed for your `from` and `to` properties.

Comment: $chatUID will be random UUID, not auth id. But will: ".read": "auth.uid != null && query.orderByChild == 'date'honor the read rules at $messageUID?

Comment: In that case, either `UUID` or `ID` would be less confusing in your rules. ;-)    But the logic is the same: if you know the chat ID, the above might work.

Comment: Or maybe I can add two more fields in $chatUID as user1: user1uuid, user2: user2uuid and put $messageUID in $chatUID/messages and allow read on messages if data.parent().child('user1').val() === auth.uid || child.parent().child('user2').val() === auth.uid ?